# Is is possible to change the default branch for merging?

Tags: github

I've forked one project on GitHub. Now when I work on it and when I want to merge PR I always have to select my repo as the one to which I want to merge PR and not the original repo that I've forked.

I use GitHub web interface when merging PRs. Is there a way to change the settings of the repo so that all PRs go to my forked repo and not the original one?

Can some code be added to some git config file?